# PHP: ZipArchive::close(): Renaming temporary file failed: No such file or directory

Tags: php, windows, cygwin, zip

I cannot create a zip file. It gives me this error. A [search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=ZipArchive%3A%3Aclose()%3A+%22Renaming+temporary+file+failed%3A+No+such+file+or+directory%22&ia=web) turned up no results. This is my function.

```
  function CompressFile($fromExtractedFile)
  {
      $archive = new ZipArchive;

      if ($archive->open($fromExtractedFile.".zip", ZipArchive::OVERWRITE | ZipArchive::CREATE) === TRUE) {
          $archive->addFile($fromExtractedFile, 'payload.csv');
          $archive->close();
      }
      else {
          throw new Exception ("Compress operation to ZIP file failed. $fromExtractedFile -> $fromExtractedFile.zip");
      }
      return $fromExtractedFile.".zip";
  }
```

Console:

```
Compressing /tmp/bing_PeUYiT
PHP Warning 'yii\base\ErrorException' with message 'ZipArchive::close(): Renaming temporary file failed: No such file or directory'
```

Docs: http://php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php

PHP 5.6, Win 8.1, Cygwin 2.5.2

Here is the same in PsySh:

```
>>> $archive = new ZipArchive
=> ZipArchive {#199
     +"status": 0,
     +"statusSys": 0,
     +"numFiles": 0,
     +"filename": "",
     +"comment": "",
   }
>>> $archive->open('/tmp/bing_PeUYiT.zip', ZipArchive::OVERWRITE|ZipArchive::CREATE)
=> true
>>> $archive->addFile('/tmp/bing_PeUYiT', 'payload.csv')
=> true
>>> $archive->close()
PHP warning:  ZipArchive::close(): Renaming temporary file failed: No such file or directory on line 1
```

Comment: I submitted a bug. https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=72818

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `ZipArchive` is broken, I used [PclZip](http://www.phpconcept.net/pclzip) instead.

> $ composer require pclzip/pclzip

```
  function compressFile2($file) {
    $zip = new PclZip($file.'.zip');
    $error = $zip->create([[PCLZIP_ATT_FILE_NAME => $file, PCLZIP_ATT_FILE_NEW_FULL_NAME => 'payload.csv']]); # array of array
    #$error = $zip->create($file, PCLZIP_OPT_REMOVE_ALL_PATH);
    if ($error == 0) trigger_error("Error : ".$zip->errorInfo(true));
    return $file.'.zip';
  }
```